# Periodic high pitched noise from St Croix Hastings pellet stove

Tags: heating

My pellet stove makes a high pitched, metal grinding, noise every 60 seconds, for 2-3 seconds

The stove just received its annual cleaning, which, unfortunately, didn't help much.  I also paid the tech to do diagnostic testing and he couldn't determine the problem because the noise briefly stopped after he cleaned it, so he couldn't hear it.

I've been told it could be the auger or the combustion fan.

The high pitched sound can be heard [at the end of this link](https://recorder.google.com/1a6083bc-ae9d-4c8b-ba95-5e701425408b)

Comment: Every 60 seconds would point more to an auger.  About the time they turn.  A fan is more continuous and much faster.  Maybe a bearing for the auger is going/needs oiling/grease.  They are usually not that hard to take apart.

Answer (score 1):

The shaft/cage weldment, which connects to the versa grate, needed anti-sieze.